# PHP : Need to search text from string data and store into array

Tags: regex

In html editor i write some text into specific format.

Example :

> Test test test   {{  LATEL1 }} test test test {{ LATEL2 }}  test test
>   test

Here i want to grab all data which are written into {{}}. I want to get all results into array.

I think this can be done using regexp. Can you help me how to do this. If there is any other simple method then let me know.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php --- https://regex101.com/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll want to using a [non-greedy "anything" quantifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) and do a global match. In this way, the `.*?` will indeed match anything, but *only* one character at a time, which will let your delimiters, the `{}`'s, match correctly:

```
{{(.*?)}}  //global
```

all your values are [captured](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) by the `()`'s, and should be available in an array (or array-like) 'matches' object after the global match is run. Here's the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW0cP0/1) output:

[image]

Note:  this alternate but semantically equivalent regex might be faster if you're using very large inputs: `{{([^{}]*)}}` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hX7jI8/2)). (the negated character class `[^{}]*` can go ahead and match (eat) all non curly brackets at one go, rather than `.*?` eating only one at a time, which means fewer steps)